# I have a query written in Oracle , would like to convert into MySQL

Tags: mysql, oracle

```
select * from 
(
select week_of, COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ID) AS weekly_developer_count,        COUNT(DISTINCT APPLICATION_ID) as weekly_app_count from
(
select PE.EVENT_DAY_UTC, to_char(next_day(PE.EVENT_DAY_UTC - 1, 'SUNDAY'),   'YYYY-MM-DD') as week_of, PE.CUSTOMER_ID, PE.APPLICATION_ID
  from tablename PE
  where 
  PE.EVENT_DAY_UTC >= SYSDATE - 90
  and PE.EVENT_DAY_UTC < SYSDATE + 1
  and PE.EVENT_NAME NOT LIKE '%.%'
)
group by  week_of
)
order by week_of desc;
```

This is the code I have it in Oracle, MySQL doesn't support NEXT_DAY. Any idea to achieve this?
I want as the output something like

```
Weekof ApplicationCount DeveloperCount
2016-17-07  50              10
2016-10-07  60              15
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own function, like described here:

[MySQL implementation of Oracle's next_day](http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/how-to/next_day)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably replace next_day with an appropriate combination of date math and [DAYOFWEEK](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek), something like:

`mydate + INTERVAL (8-DAYOFWEEK(mydate)) DAY`

should work for Sunday

Answer (score 0):

Here's a MySQL stored function you can define that does the same thing as Oracle's `NEXT_DAY()`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION next_day (date DATE, dow VARCHAR(10)) RETURNS DATE 
RETURN FROM_DAYS(
    TO_DAYS(date) - DAYOFWEEK(date)
    + IF(DAYOFWEEK(date) >= FIND_IN_SET(dow,  'Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday'), 7, 0)
    + FIND_IN_SET(dow, 'Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday')
  );
```